# How to use a node under a user's node to create a list?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, firebase, uitableview

I am trying to create two tables with a segmented button that toggles between two. I currently have the code to toggle the visibility of the two tables. I am using firebase and want to be able to differentiate the users by a specific "tag" that I put into their json tree.

Example:

```
Users:
     |
    4774893HUjd8
               |
              Name: John Doe
              Email: example@example.com
              Tag: Macro
     |
    38849HHIJDO877
               |
               Name: Jane Doe
               Email: example2@example.com
               Tag: Micro
```

I want to be able to keep them in the Users Node. I don't want to create a Macro and Micro user nodes because if a user upgrades their account I can just update the tag in firebase.

Here is how I am currently loading the data in my project:

```
func updateDataArray() {
    
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            
            let user = User()
            //self.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            user.Name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
            user.Email = dictionary["Email"] as? String
            user.ProfileImageUrl = dictionary["ProfileImageUrl"] as? String
            user.UID = dictionary["UID"] as? String
            user.UserCategory = dictionary["UserCategory"] as? String
            
            self.users.append(user)
            self.userName.append(user.Name!)
            self.filteredNames.append(user.Name!)
            
            print(dictionary)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

I am using swift and firebase as my backend. I could really use the help and want to figure this out as soon as possible.

Edit: Here is my user struct that would have been helpful.

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    var Name: String?
    var Email: String?
    var ProfileImageUrl: String?
    var UID: String?
    var Tag: String?
}
```

I have also added the two different arrays that you suggested.

I changed the table counts and inputs to their respective tag array.

I am having a hard time updating the children values and appending the proper arrays.

```
func createDataArray() {
    
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            
            let user = User()
            //self.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            user.Name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
            user.Email = dictionary["Email"] as? String
            user.UID = dictionary["UID"] as? String
            user.Tag = dictionary["Tag"] as? String
            
            if user.Tag == "Macro" {
                            self.macroUsersArray.append(user)
            } else if user.Tag == "Micro" {
                            self.microUsersArray.append(user)
                        }
            
            self.users.append(user)
            self.userName.append(user.Name!)
            self.filteredNames.append(user.Name!)
            
            print(dictionary)
            print(self.macroUsersArray)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Here is the code I am trying to use to remove the updated child node "tag" and update my tables' array,

```
func updateDataArray() {
    
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            
            let user = User()
            //self.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            user.Name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
            user.Email = dictionary["Email"] as? String
            user.UID = dictionary["UID"] as? String
            user.Tag = dictionary["Tag"] as? String
            
            if user.Tag == "Macro" {
                self.microUsersArray.removeAll()
            } else if user.Tag == "Micro" {
                self.macroUsersArray.removeAll()
                        }
            
            self.users.append(user)
            self.userName.append(user.Name!)
            self.filteredNames.append(user.Name!)
            
            print(dictionary)
            print(self.macroUsersArray)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    
    }
```

Comment: Two things; you should probably be using the users uid as the key to their node within the users node e.g. `/users/uid_x`. Second thing is, what are you asking and what isn't working? The question mentions creating a list but there's no indication of that within the code - a list... of what? Other users? Favorite foods? Oh, and this `user.Name!` is dangerous as it's an optional `as? String`. And you don't need this `DispatchQueue.main.async` in firebase closures as UI calls are automatically called on the main thread.

Comment: Hey Jay. Thanks for the comment. I want to be able to load the users into 2 different groups to display in 2 different tables. I want to load all them there same and then differentiate them by the tag that is under each of the users node. In my example, the tag is macro and micro. I want to have access to all the other information as well as the tag so the tag can't be before all the other info. I also want to be able to update the tag from macro to micro or vice versa without having to re-enter the information. That way I can move them in the table with the small change.

Comment: I forgot to mention that those numbers I made up were uids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain I understand the question but it appears from the comments the OP wants to read in all users and based on a child node, separate them into two lists (Micro and Macro) to be used as tableView dataSources.

Start with a user class to hold the user information

```
class UserClass {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    var email = ""
    var tag = ""

    convenience init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.uid = withSnap.key
        self.name = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        self.email = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Email").value as? String ?? "No Email"
        self.tag = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Tag").value as? String ?? "Micro"
    }
}
```

then two arrays to be used as tableView datasources. One contains the Micro users and the other contains the Macro users. These would typically be class vars the tableViewDataSource functions can access:

```
var macroUsersArray = [UserClass]()
var microUsersArray = [UserClass]()
```

then the Firebase code to read in all users, iterate over them and add then to the appropriate array

```
func readAllUsersAndAddToDatasource() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("Users")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allUsersSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for childSnap in allUsersSnap {
            let user = UserClass(withSnapshot: childsnap)
            if user.Tag = "Macro" {
                self.macroUsersArray.append(user)
            } else {
                self.microUsersArray.append(user)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT:**

One possible workflow if we are NOT using Firebase events (e.g. users are read by observeSingleEvent as shown above)

1. Select the user to change from Macro to Micro in the Macro array
2. Change the users property
3. Remove the user from the Macro array (reload Macro tableView)
4. Add the user to the Micro array (reload Micro tableView
5. Update the user's property in Firebase

If you're using events then the pattern is different

add a .changed event to the users node to watch for changes.

1. Select the user to change from Macro to Micro in the Macro array
2. Get the users key (uid) and write the change to firebase, firing a change event
3. Within the changed closure, remove the user from the Macro array (reload tableView)
4. Add the user to the Micro array (reload tableView)

Comment: Hey Jay. I am so close to figuring this out with your help. I edited my question to give you a little more information and show you where I currently am at. Thanks again for all your help. Hopefully this is a super quick fix for you so I can give you a break before something else breaks down haha.

Comment: @NewCoder Remember that conceptually,  if you have two arrays (one for Micro users and one for Macro users) and you change a user from one to the other, you need to remove them from one array and add them to the other, then refresh your tableView to reflect that change. That being said, depending on how you're using firebase you may want to observe the objects in question for .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved so if you make a change in Firebase itself, your code will automatically be aware of that change and can update the respective dataSource array.

Comment: Oh awesome. I apologize in advance, but how would I go about setting it up for when I change the tag in firebase, it just updates on the app?

Comment: @NewCoder It's going to depend on your use case. My answer loads all of the users at once and puts them in corresponding arrays whereas your code adds an observer to observe future childAdded events. I don't know if thats what you want to do or not. There are two options; 1) Load in the users per my answer and when something  changes, write that data to Firebase as well as change it in the array. 2) Write the data to Firebase and let the firebase observers update the arrays based on those events. More info on events [Work with Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

Comment: I tried changing observe.ChildAdded to observe.ChildChanged and the table isn't loading now. I would like to use your second example. I can go in on my end in firebase to change the users tag and have it automatically change on all users' app.

Comment: @NewCoder you need to review the documentation to explore the options. .childChanged does not do an initial load of data, it just observes changes in existing data. If you want an initial load you need use .childAdded or .value. From the docs: *.childAdded - This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added*. You will need to add those event observers to your code and then whan something changes, the code in the event closure will fire like a .childRemoved. In the closure find the child in the array and remove it and then reload the tableview.

Comment: @NewCoder I would advise against trying to implement technology you don't understand yet in the middle of your project - that's going to be super frustrating. I would suggest crafting a simple ToDo app that stores toDo items in firebase. Implement .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved observers on your data and learn how that works. Once you get it, you got it and can implement the solution into your project. Just my .02.

Comment: Hey Jay. Sorry for getting upset. Today has been the worst and I am trying to get this done after trying for the last three weeks. I updated the question to reflect where I currently am. I have renamed the updateArray() to CreateArray() and the new update array is where I am updating the value. The only problem is that when the data is changed and updated it doesn't change the arrays they were originally in and append them to the new category (indexPath out of range error again). How can I fix this?

Comment: @NewCoder We are going beyond what can be done here on SO but I've updated the answer with two options. One for reading the users once as shown in my answer and the other if you want to rely on events to propagate the changes.

Comment: Did you read the code that I added in the edit? I created an update array for when the user's tag is changed. I am getting the error "indexPath out of range" still and want to know what to change in my code.

Comment: @NewCoder I did review it and it not the right direction. There's no reason to create a new user. All you need to do is get the users key from the snapshot, locate the user in the array you're removing them from and remove it, then add the same user with the updated property into the other array. e.g. you're creating a new user and you don't need to do that.

Comment: Oh, and the question is morphing into a different question so it should probably BE a different question. The initial question was how to *I am using firebase and want to be able to differentiate the users by a specific "tag"* and my answer solves that. What you're asking now goes beyond that initial question. I would suggest getting the first part working, then make some attempts and 'changing' a user property and moving them from one dataSource to the other. If unsuccessful, open another question about that issue. It will help keep SO questions more on point.

Comment: Hey Jay! I asked the new question. I'd love to get your help to finish this function in mu app.

Comment: Hey Jay. I have a new problem I was hoping you could help give some insight to. I really appreciate everything you've done to help me and I can't thank you enough. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983561/download-images-for-a-specific-user-sort-by-date-uploaded-and-display-5-of-the I thought it was a good question and maybe you could give some insight why someone would down vote with your take on the solution. Thank you in advance!!!